# Ubuntu 14.04 installation - hide ssd builtin disk

Tags: partitioning, system-installation, ssd

I'm trying to install ubuntu 14.04 in my main disk (sda). The laptop (acer aspire s3) comes with a built-in (soldered! :_() 20GB ssd which appears to be broken, it spits I/O errors in both GParted and diskpart (windows).

The issue comes when trying to select the partition to install (sda), it seems to freeze after reading the ssd MBR (or whatever partition table the ssd uses).

Is there any way to hide the ssd to the ubuntu installer?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I was searching for an answer to the exact same question, since I am more or less in your situation with 128GB SK hynix SSD drive on DELL XPS 15 (L521X).

On your question - I would suggest to check your BIOS for onboard SSD disable function available, and then disable the drive for good.

(this may also include BIOS update)